# Google Apps Script: TypeError: sheet.getActiveSheet is not a function - Global variable just started failing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

In my google apps script, I have the following set outside of a function as global variables:

```
// Globals
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var actSheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();
```

today I started seeing this error in the chrome console.

> Google Apps Script: TypeError: sheet.getActiveSheet is not a function

this code has been working fine for months... grrr.... This error is causing my `onOpen()` function to fail (because the script is dying on the declaration of `var actSheet`), so my sheets no longer have drop down menus displaying.

the idea behind the var sheet and var actSheet is they are global variables used throughout my code functions.

Comment: The active sheet is generally `Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]` when you first open your spreadsheet or if you open it with a script. So if you moved your sheets then the active sheet is changing.  `Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]` is the most right sheet which could be  hidden.

Comment: Actually I meant to say it's the sheet farthest to the left.  Thinking what you want a typing it correctly are one of the things that I'm beginning to lose.

Comment: This failed in the same way yesterday, but works today. Something in Google land changed yesterday and has possibly been corrected